# Run NofloJS using NodeJS in Windows

Tags: node.js, noflo

As per NoflowJS is concerned it is a visual programming interface of JavaScript. I got stuck in this syntax :

```
    $ ./node_modules/.bin/noflo -h
```

I want the syntax for Windows Operating System. Link to NofloJS: http://noflojs.org/documentation/

Also recommend some best visual programming for JavaScript.

Comment: From memory (it's been a while since I've used Windows) you can't run a script directly unless it has an executable file extension. I think you'd need to run something like `node node_modules/.bin/noflo -h`, from your home directory I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should simply be:

```
$ node node_modules\.bin\noflo -h
```

Make sure that you have `node.exe` available in your [Path environment variable](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx). If it isn't, you can of course also just run it with a fully-qualified path.